# Android SQL query synatax

Tags: android, sqlite

I`m trying to run an SQL query on SQLite database in android , but it crashes when I run the query.

in my DBhelper i have a function getFlex which takes string variables passed from spinners and edittext strings.

The info passed are represent columns in database
airportIata is text
designation is text
weight is REAL

here is the function

```
public Cursor getFlex(String iata, String designation, String weight) { 
    String airportiata = iata;
    String runway = designation;
    String enteredWeight = weight;

    String sql = "SELECT airportIata, runwayDesignation, flex, weight, v1, vr, v2, minV1, minVr, minV2, engOut FROM flexes WHERE airportIata = ? AND runwayDesignation = ? AND weight >= ? LIMIT 1";

    Cursor c =  db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{airportiata, runway, enteredWeight});

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

here is where i call this function in MainActivity with a button Click

```
protected void calculate(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    airportiata = (((airportspinner) airportSp.getSelectedItem()).getairportiata().toString());
    designation = (runwaySp.getSelectedItem().toString());
    EditText weightTV = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightET);

    weightText = weightTV.getText().toString();
    String message = "";

    Cursor flexCur = myDbHelper.getFlex(airportiata, designation, weightText);

    if (flexCur.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            // Process the data:
            int flex = flexCur.getInt(2);
            float weight = flexCur.getInt(3);
            int v1 = flexCur.getInt(4);
            int vr = flexCur.getInt(5);
            int v2 = flexCur.getInt(6);
            int minV1 = flexCur.getInt(7);
            int minVr = flexCur.getInt(8);
            int minV2 = flexCur.getInt(9);
            int engOut = flexCur.getInt(10);

            // Append data to the message:
            message += "flex = " + flex
                       +", weight =" + weight
                       +", v1=" + v1
                       +", vr=" + vr
                       +", v2=" + v2
                       +", minV1=" + minV1
                       +", minVr=" + minVr
                       +", minV2=" + minV2
                       +", engOut=" + engOut
                       +"\n";
        } while(flexCur.moveToNext());
    }

    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayTV);
    display.setText(airportiata + " " + designation + " " + weightText);

    TextView fromDB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.formDB);
    fromDB.setText(message);
}
```

And here is my LogCat:

```
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702): Process: com.waleed.sqlite1, PID: 702
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.waleed.sqlite1.DatabaseHelper.getFlex(DatabaseHelper.java:209)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.waleed.sqlite1.MainActivity.calculate(MainActivity.java:71)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.waleed.sqlite1.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare here is LogCat: 12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702): Process: com.waleed.sqlite1, PID: 702
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 18:02:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.waleed.sqlite1.DatabaseHelper.getFlex(DatabaseHelper.java:209)

Comment: You are the only person on the planet who knows what line 209 of `DatabaseHelper.java` is. You have a `NullPointerException` there. You will need to see what that line is, see what is `null`, and then figure out why it is `null`.

Comment: @CommonsWare never mind, I found the mistake, I didn`t call db = this.getReadableDatabase(); before the cursor in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake

I didn`t call db = this.getReadableDatabase(); before the Cursor in the function.

Thanks anyway :)